# Version of HTML after omitting DOCTYPE html tag?

Tags: android, html, android-webview, version, doctype

If I omit the tag `<DOCTYPE html ...>` in my **HTML file**, which **version of HTML** will be used by my **browser** while reading my HTML file?

Will it be set to the **latest available version** by default or it will be set to a **lower version** of HTML? Will this vary from browser to browser?

**EDIT**

How will the HTML page be rendered on a WebView in Android? Which HTML version will be used?

Comment: What do you mean by *ignoring*? I think you must mean *omitting* it.

Comment: Yes I meant omitting. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using a [doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) causes the browser to render the page using "quirks mode".

This means that the page's output could vary by browser vendor, depending on how they've set up their quirks mode to function.

You can find more detailed information about quirks mode [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

WHATWG is now [standardizing interoperable quirks](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/), so the browser's quirks mode is probably based on a variation of this.

Despite all of this, it's recommended that you always include a doctype in a web page to control how the page is being rendered.